# Format datatable using VBA (values are as Double but String is needed for formatting)

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, formatting, charts, format

Currently working on a vba script that makes charts automatically. I would like to add a datatable which is done using:
.HasDataTable = True

However I would like to show the values of series as percentages. Currently the value is defined as a Double containing all the values but not the right formatting.
[image]

Using Format() or FormatPercent() will give the right values but returned in a String. This works for the datatable but not for the chart itself since it doesn't recognize the values anymore.

My question comes down to whether it is possible to show the values as percentages in both the datatable and the chart? Without VBA it is easily done by formatting the data in the cells itself. The problem is that for formatting a String is returned but for the graph Integers or Doubles are needed.

Any help is welcome and please let me know if the question is unclear.

Below is part of the code. If I dim Ratio as String and use FormatPercent() I get the requested formatting but then the values in Ratio ar no longer doubles so it doesn't give the required chart.

```
Dim Ratio() As Double   
Dim labels() As String

ReDim Ratio(1 To Height)
ReDim labels(1 To Height)


For Each Column In sArray
        labels(i) = Sheets(DataSheetName).Cells(LabelsRow, Column)
        Ratio(i) = Math.Round(Sheets(DataSheetName).Cells(LabelsRow + 3, Column), 2)
        i = i + 1
Next Column


Set myChtObj = Sheets(DrawSheetName).ChartObjects.Add(Left:=Left, Width:=Width, Top:=Top, Height:=HeightGraph)

Dim srsNew1 As Series

 ' Add the chart
With myChtObj.Chart
    .ChartArea.Fill.Visible = False
    .ChartArea.Border.LineStyle = xlNone
    .PlotArea.Format.Fill.Solid
    .PlotArea.Format.Fill.Transparency = 1
    .HasTitle = True
    .ChartTitle.text = Title
    .HasLegend = False

    .Axes(xlValue).TickLabels.NumberFormat = "0%"
    .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).HasTitle = False

    'add data table
    .HasDataTable = True

     ' Make Line chart
    .ChartType = xlLine


     ' Add series
    Set srsNew1 = .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
    With srsNew1
        .Values = Ratio
        .XValues = labels
        .Name = "Ratio"
        .Interior.Color = clr3 'RGB(194, 84, 57)
    End With


End With
```

In adiition to the above. The picture below might illustrate best what I want.

[image]

Comment: To convert a string into the double you can use the VBScript function CDbl. Please let me know if the answer is unclear :)

Comment: Hi duDE, thanks for responding. That does work if the value in the string would be a true double, for example 2.67. However the string now contains the value 267% which can't be converted back to a double. 

Maybe I should rephrase my question, the chart should contain the true value which is a double. But in addition I would like the datatable to be formatted to show the values as percentages

Comment: Can you add the appropriate part of this script to your question? It would be helpful.

Comment: Just drop the `%` from it and use `.format`

Comment: Hi duDE, I've attached part of the script.

Comment: Hi duDE, I've attached part of the script. Hope this illustrates the problem better. If I store the data in Ratio() I have to dim it As String which results in a correct table but not in a correct graph

Comment: Raystafarian, True that works off course but the whole point is that I would like to see the percentages. I know its possible without using VBA so I would like to know whether its also possible in VBA. If it cant be done I will leave the percentages

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm confused. You use `each column` to populate the dblArr and strArr from a sheet. Then you create a new series with those arrays, yes? And the issue is that your strArr doesn't match its axis' format?

Comment: Hi Raystafarian, that's correct., I create a new series with those array's. The values of the series are given by the array Ratio which is a Double and thus gives the values as Doubles in the datatable.

Comment: What if you just make them variants? At least then pass them to the right var type before populating each thing?

Comment: have you tried recording a macro with the desired settings?